# Solving $\det{(A+\epsilon B)}=0$ for large, symmetric and dense $A$ and $B$

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

In an algorithm I am writing, I need to solve the equation

$$ \det{(A+\epsilon B)} = 0, $$

for the smallest value of $\epsilon$, given large ($n$x$n$ ideally up to 150x150), dense and symmetric A and B. In the algorithm, I invert $B$ and have Mathematica solve the equation $\det(B^{-1}A+\epsilon I)=0$ by Eigenvalues[$B^{-1}A$].

This works fine for $n<20$, then I start getting errors:

> Result for Inverse of badly conditioned matrix [$B$] may contain significant numerical errors.

As the algorithm runs, $B$ becomes more singular and wrecks the calculations. One thing that would help my algorithm is a way to solve the original equation fast in Mathematica without inverting $B$, but I am struggling to come up with one!

Anyone know a way?

Comment: This really needs a concrete example. Are the matrices comprised of approximate reals? Rationals? Gorillas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the generalized form of [`Eigenvalues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eigenvalues). Example matrices:

```
SeedRandom[1]
{A, B} = RandomReal[1, {2, 4, 4}];
```

Compare:

```
Eigenvalues[Inverse[B] . A]
Eigenvalues[{A, B}]
```

> {2.41802, 1.42315, 0.685593, -0.296285}
>
> {2.41802, 1.42315, 0.685593, -0.296285}